# OPENCV Python interface implementation

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I finished implementing an image processing algorithm in C++, and I want to build an Python interface for that for easy integration with other codes(mostly machine learning code written in Python).

How is the python interface of OpenCV implemented? I want to emulate it. I think they don't use SWIG but something else.

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/6618/how-python-api-is-generated/?answer=6940#post-id-6940